# How to know if flutter app is in production mode?

Tags: flutter, dart, release, production-environment, dev-to-production

I am configuring an API endpoint using the flutter package `dio`! I have two API endpoints: one for development and another for production. I want my `dio` baseURL to automatically switch between development and production endpoints.

Just like so

```
Dio(
  baseURL: isProduction ? productionBaseURL : developmentBaseURL
  ......
      );
```

How to know if my app is in production environment in Dart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use flavors in flutter to setup two different environments for your app, one for testing and one for production. You can refer [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/flavors) official documentation.

Answer (score 7):

Just check the [`kReleaseMode`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/kReleaseMode-constant.html) global constant. It's `true` if the application was compiled in release mode.

Or, I'd recommend that this info comes from an environment variable so it follows one of the bullets from [The Twelve-Factor App](https://12factor.net/) (the [Config](https://12factor.net/config) bullet). And to get it and check do the following.

For example, `IS_PRODUCTION` system environment variable:

```
final isProduction = Platform.environment['IS_PRODUCTION'] == '1';
```

Or, getting the `dart-defines` compile-time environment variables:

```
const isProduction = String.fromEnvironment('IS_PRODUCTION') == '1';
```

There are 2 ways to set a `dart-define`:

1. `flutter run --dart-define=IS_PRODUCTION=1`, or;
2. `flutter build <bundle> --dart-define=IS_PRODUCTION=1`;

   Where `<bundle>` can be: `aar`, `apk`, `appbundle`, `bundle,` `web`, or `windows`.

Note that `dart-define` is compiled into the app itself. That's why they accept being `const` declaration. From the command-line docs it says:

> Additional key-value pairs that will be available as constants from the `String.fromEnvironment`, `bool.fromEnvironment`, `int.fromEnvironment`, and `double.fromEnvironment` constructors.

Comment: What if you want to run debug build against your production server or a release build against your development server?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @activout.se. That's why I've added a preferred option to the answer.

Comment: I'd recommend a bool, so that a missing bool will just be false.

Comment: Alright! It perfectly worked 

Answer (score 1):

You have to decide and check yourself what "production" means in a way that suits your app. It can be a runtime setting for example in in shared_preferences, or it can be a compile-time setting you pass to `flutter build`.

I have implemented a pub.dev package [firebase_options_selector](https://github.com/activout/firebase_options_selector) that does this at runtime with a Firebase backend. You can use my source code as inspiration if you want.